# How to get phone through document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, variables

So I have this code

```
<span data-testid="phone_number" class="-ROQ5" data-default-style="{&quot;backgroundColor&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;border&quot;:&quot;&quot;}" style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5); border: 2px solid rgb(50, 195, 105);">+880500002636</span>
```

I need to get document.querySelector phone number 880500002636
How I can do this?

I need to create JavaScript variables for google ads

Comment: Based on _what_ do you want to select the element? Class? One of the `data-` attributes? Something else?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should be included in your question as a [mcve]. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).